# Why jQuery selector can't work but getElementById works in this scenario?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Here is the HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="access.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="trigger"></button>
    <img id= "testElement" style= "position: absolute; border-color: white; top:340px; left:615px;" width="34px" height= "34px" />
  </body>
</html>
```

And the access.js file is:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
  $('#trigger').click(function(){
    $('#testElement').src="success.png";
    //THIS WON'T WORK.
    document.getElementById('testElement').src= "success.png";
    //BUT THIS WORKS.
  });
});
```

I know that if I use **$**, the return object is a jQuery object. It's not the same as getElementById. But why the jQuery selector can't work here?

I need the jQuery object to make more operations like "append/style"...

Thanks.

**UPDATE**
Too many correct answers appeared at almost the same time... Please give more explanation to let me decide who I should give the credit, thanks!

Sorry for my poor understanding of your correct answers... I just want more details.

Are all the attribute nodes (src/width/height...) not the property of jQuery object? So does the jQuery selector only select DOM Element Node like img/p/li/div node ? (<> causes some error.)

PLEASE TAKE A LOOK AT THE UPDATED INFORMATION...
Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A jQuery element is a DOM element wrapped in an *array-like* jQuery object so you have access to all the jQuery methods, but that means you "lose" access to the original DOM methods and properties. You can either use a jQuery method or grab the original DOM element to be able to use the vanilla properties.

```
$('#testElement').attr('src', 'success.png');
$('#testElement')[0].src = 'success.png';
                --^-- get DOM element
```

Answer (score 8):

Because you need to use the `.attr()` jQuery method on the jQuery object:

```
$('#testElement').attr("src", "success.png");
```

Comment: Why? Can you give more explain?

Comment: @Stallman Sure. `src` is a property on a plain old DOM element. When you use jQuery, you are interacting with a jQuery wrapper and not the actual DOM element. jQuery itself will set the DOM element's `src` property for you.

Answer (score 4):

Should be

```
$('#testElement').prop("src","success.png");  //1.6 and above
```

OR

```
$('#testElement').attr("src","success.png");  //before 1.6
```

The way you access property in JavaScript and JQuery is different

```
document.getElementById('testElement').src= "success.png";
```

can also be achieved with

```
$('#testElement')[0].src = "success.png";
```

- [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)
- [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

Answer (score 3):

`src` is not a property of a jQuery object. You need to do

```
$('#testElement').attr('src', 'success.png')
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this instead :

```
$('#testElement').attr("src","success.png");
```

Or if you are using latest version of jquery than you could use:

```
$('#testElement').prop("src","success.png");
```

Comment: The use of `prop` is meant for properties and `attr` for attributes. They are interchangeable but not _semantically_ the same. `src` is an attribute AFAIK.

Answer (score 3):

jQuery object has no `src` property thats a DOM object property which is why getElementById works, use [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) or [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) to set matched elements attributes or properties

```
$('#testElement').attr('src',"success.png");
$('#testElement').prop('src',"success.png");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>$('#testElement');
```

> [<img id=​"testElement" style=​"position:​ absolute;​ border-color:​ white;​ top:​340px;​ left:​615px;​" width=​"34px" height=​"34px">​]

As you can see $ returns an array of DOM elements. Similar to `document.getElementsBy(Class|Tag)Name`, if you want a DOM comparison.

When dealing with an ID (#testElement), you're about sure there's only one element like this, so you can access it directly with `$('#testElement')[0]` (ie, the first element in the array). After that, you're good to go and treat it just the way you'd do it in plain JS.

Comment: But I only create a DOM element whose ID is testElement, why the selector would return an array of DOM elements. There is no another element whose ID is that.

Comment: Because $ works with any kind of conditions: #xxxx, .xxxx etc. So, it returns as a standard an array. Don't try and fight against it. Just accept the facts, and use them to your advantage. Asking why? won't get you anywhere.